# Detect if an android device has mobile data capability

Tags: android, tablet

I want to detect whether or not a device has mobile data capability. By mobile data capability I don't mean an active or connected mobile data connection, just the ability to use mobile data.

I currently use the following

```
if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)) {
    //I assume device has mobile data capability
}
```

This works fine for most cases but one - If the device does not have calling facility but has the capability to utilize a cellular network for data connection only. Such devices are typically tablets which have a SIM card slot but it can be used only for data connection, not calling.

How can I detect whether the device has mobile data capability in this case and in all other cases? What is the best method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Posting it for others who might need it.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo ni = cm
        .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

if (ni == null) {
    // Device does not have mobile data capability
}
```

From the documentation of getNetworkInfo(int networkType):

> **Parameters:** networkType integer specifying which networkType in which you're interested.
>
> **Returns:** a NetworkInfo object for the requested network type or **null
>   if the type is not supported by the device**.  This method requires the
>   caller to hold the permission
>   android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE.

This method can be extended to check for other types of network as well. Just put the required networkType in getNetworkInfo().

Personally, I perform this test only if 
`getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)` 
returns false. This check can then confirm whether or not device has mobile data capability even though it does not have telephony feature (which is the case with some tablets). If device has FEATURE_TELEPHONY, I assume it has mobile data capability. This way we can possibly reduce execution time in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

hmm I have not tested this yet but if it has a data connection then its location over network probably is enabled, thus you can use FEATURE_LOCATION_NETWORK

Comment: I'm not sure if it will give the desired result. FEATURE_LOCATION_NETWORK may actually depend on the telephony cell tower id or something. If you are just going to use mobile data(when you are not in a wifi zone), you don't even have to stay registered on the cell network all the time. Maybe the device just turns off the cell radio completely when mobile data is turned off(device switches to wifi or user manually turns off data). So location feature is more likely to rely on telephony. Unfortunately, I can't test and know for sure as I don't actually have one of those devices. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use `ConnectivityManager` and `NetworkInfo` to check the current state of connection:

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo eventInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    //first check to see if an active connection exists
    if (eventInfo != null
            && eventInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
        //now checks for the type of connection
        switch(eventInfo.getType()) {
             case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE:
             case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_DUN:
             case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI:
             case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_MMS:
             case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_SUPL:
             //is mobile connection
             break;
        }
    } else {
         //device currently in a disconnected state, including connecting 
    }
```

*psudo code, may not 100% work on copy & paste

Comment: What does this code tell about device's ability to use mobile data? Only in case active network is connected and is of type mobile(and related) can we say that device that device has mobile data capability but in all other cases we just cannot say for sure that the device does NOT have mobile data capability.